# Setting a condition so that no results are displayed if the condition is not met

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to have a chart be blank rather than showing results if the size of the data that populates the chart is too small. I have a variable `ID` in which each case has a unique value. In a case where I don't want any data to show if there are less than 10 cases, I figured I'd need to set up a calculated field that would do something like the following:

```
IF COUNTD([ID]) < 10 THEN ....
```

But I can't figure out what command to call so that it shows no data. Would anyone have a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated filed with calculation "COUNTD([ID])<10" .It would be a Boolean filter.Now drag and drop the calculation to the filter shelf and set it to either "TRUE" or "Exclude False".

Comment: The chart still appears, with some cases appearing to be removed. I'd like to have all cases removed if the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: Ok i believe Case is a dimension in your use case. If that is  the case you can update the calculated field for the case, something like below

Comment: TOTAL(COUNTD([ID]))<10